# What are some reputible .IT domain registrars?

Tags: domain, domain-registrar

I normally use godaddy for my domain names but I need to purchase an .it domain and they don't offer that tld. Are there any good European or Italian registrars that are friendly and wont price gouge me? I can't seem to find any that look reputable.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off-topic per the updated [faq](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gandi.net has them and they're great !

Answer (score 0):

inwx.de is also a great company.